# How to set a default size for text from a table

Tags: pdftex

I have this simple table that scales based on the text size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,table]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm,     top=2cm]{geometry} %a4paper, letterpaper
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Test}} &                        \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

All is good but when the text is very short the table and also the text is very big (like in the above example).

Is there a way to set a default size for text in order to prevent this huge font? For example, I need somehow to check if there is enough space set a font size of 12 else scale the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typeset the table into a box and measure it. If it is too big scale it to fit:

[image]

### Notes:

- The first table was not too big so was not scaled. The second table was too big and hence was scaled to fit.
- Consider using the `booktabs` package for you tables.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,table,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm,     top=2cm]{geometry} %a4paper, letterpaper
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newsavebox{\MyTable}

\newcommand*{\ResizeTableIfTooBig}[1]{%
    %% #1 = table
    \savebox{\MyTable}{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd\MyTable<\linewidth
        \usebox{\MyTable}%
    \else
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\MyTable}}%
    \fi
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ResizeTableIfTooBig{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Test}} &                        \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\noindent
\ResizeTableIfTooBig{%
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Test}} & \\ \hline
        1 & Some very very long text that is too wide to fit here so table will need to be scaled to get it to fit\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you very much for your time. This solved my problem.

Comment: @John: Your welcome. However, if you don't mind including another package, egreg's solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

The package `adjustbox` can do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,table]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  headheight=2cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  top=2cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\multicolumncolor}[4]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{#2}{\cellcolor[HTML]{#3}#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumncolor{1}{c}{9B9B9B}{\textbf{Test}} &   \\
 \hline
1                                              & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```